# Error: "User needs to define RAPIDJSON_ENDIAN" and "error in include chain: expected parameter declarator" when using simpledom rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm just trying to test out `rapidjson` `simpledom.cpp` example [that was displayed on their website](http://rapidjson.org/), however when I add it to my project on uVision I get the following error on line
`#include "rapidjson/document.h"`:

```
error in include chain (encodings.h): expected parameter declarator
error in include chain (encodedstream.h): expected parameter declaratory
```

And I'm not too familiar with C++ so looking at `encodings.h` and `encodedstream.h` does not enlighten me on what I need to do to run the simple example.

And, idk if this is relevant, but I'm also getting the following error when I try to compile:

```
compiling simpledom.cpp...
.\rapidjson/rapidjson.h(249): error:  #35: #error directive: Unknown machine endianess detected. User needs to define RAPIDJSON_ENDIAN.   
  #    error Unknown machine endianess detected. User needs to define RAPIDJSON_ENDIAN.
```

If anyone could advise me on what I'm doing wrong that would be great!

### Code

**simpledom.cpp**

```
// JSON simple example
// This example does not handle errors.

#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace rapidjson;

int main() {
    // 1. Parse a JSON string into DOM.
    const char* json = "{\"project\":\"rapidjson\",\"stars\":10}";
    Document d;
    d.Parse(json);

    // 2. Modify it by DOM.
    Value& s = d["stars"];
    s.SetInt(s.GetInt() + 1);

    // 3. Stringify the DOM
    StringBuffer buffer;
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    d.Accept(writer);

    // Output {"project":"rapidjson","stars":11}
    std::cout << buffer.GetString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling for ARM? rapidjson.h doesn't have auto-detect of endianness for ARM (since it could be either, in general), so try adding `#define RAPIDJSON_ENDIAN 0` before including the rapidjson header files (if you are running little-endian ARM, which is most likely) or define it to 1 if bigendian.  I don't know about the 'include chain errors', it may be related to the #error directive.

Comment: @greggo yes I'm using the ARM compiler...I've got it to not produce that error by doing `#define RAPIDJSON_ENDIAN RAPIDJSON_LITTLEENDIAN` in `rapidjson.h`. Tho I'm now running into another error and anyways, it turns out my board doesn't have enough space for this library. Thanks tho!

Comment: You might try building with `-Os`  ; there are a lot of inlines in the code, and opportunities for a compiler to aggressively inline, so suppressing some of that may help. Also, if you can invoke the library functions in as few places as possible (preferably all in one C++ file) - wrap a function around the call, and then call that function as needed - that could help too. And, link-time optimization may help(?)

Comment: And a lot of it is not written to be compact, at all. I recall looking through just some of the code and seeing a number of places where `#ifdef RAPIDJSON_LESS_HUGE` could be a useful  enhancement.